# Eclipse doesnt show -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake debug logs

Tags: eclipse

I have configured eclipse runconfigurations as follows;

at Run configurations-->Arguments

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake
```

eclipse runtime.
But still at console im not getting any debug logs.(SSL handshake logs)

Why is that?
I get only my system.print statements in console.

Comment: Make sure, to configure it as _VM argument_, not as _Program argument_. In case you did, please improve your question. In the run configuration is a _Show Command Line_ button. When you run your application from the command line and get the same issue, then it can't be an Eclipse thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, to configure it as ***VM argument***, not as *Program argument*.